# Failed to connect to the database. Retrying in 10 seconds. TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed

Tags: serverpod

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRUKP.png)

I can't connect to the database, No matter how I try it can't connect, can I ask for solutions from everyone?
SERVERPOD version: 1.1.1, dart: 3.1.2 (stable) (Tue Sep 12 16:26:23 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64", time: 2023-11-05 13:07:14.530867Z
mode: development, role: monolith, logging: normal, serverId: default
Failed to connect to the database. Retrying in 10 seconds. TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed
Database configuration:
database host: localhost
database port: 8090
database name: demopod
database user: postgres
database require SSL: false
database unix socket: false
database pass: ********

Failed to connect to the database. Retrying in 10 seconds. TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed
Failed to connect to the database. Retrying in 10 seconds. TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed
Failed to connect to the database. Retrying in 10 seconds. TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed

Comment: I was able to solve this by truncating the serverpod_runtime_settings table in the database.